# Combine single and double space

Tags: spacing, bibliographies

I need to write a bibligraphy with single space for each entry, but double space between entries, before inserting the bibliography I write

```
\begin{singlespace}
```

which makes the whole thing single spaced, is there a way I can order that between entries there should be double space?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace} 

\usepackage{titlesec}

\RequirePackage{setspace}[1998/04/8]

\begin{document}

\title{Three Essays on Meritocracy for Teachers and Teacher Quality in Colombia} 

\tableofcontents  

\listoffigures 

\listoftables

\topmatter{Acknowledgments}

\topmatter{Abstract}

\clearpage

\newpage

\newpage \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}  

\begin{singlespace}

bibligraphy should go here

\end{singlespace}
```

---

The document class is report and the relevant packages are

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\RequirePackage{setspace}[1998/04/8]

And this is what I'm running

\title{Three Essays on Meritocracy for Teachers and Teacher Quality in Colombia}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\topmatter{Acknowledgments}

\topmatter{Abstract}

\clearpage

\newpage

\newpage \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}

\begin{singlespace}

bibligraphy should go here

\end{singlespace}

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's important to know how you generate your bibliography: are you typing it directly or use `bibtex` or `biblatex+biber`? What document class are you using?

Comment: while an answer to @egreg's request would provide valuable information, i'll assume that each bib entry is a separate paragraph.  if so, then `\setlength{\parsep}{\baselineskip}` should give the separation you want using `singlespace`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using NAtbib to generate the bibliography because I need the references to use the names in the text (so I think that means I'm not using bibtex?). I wrote \setlength{\parsep}{\baselineskip} but is not working, let me know if there is anything else I can try

Comment: Thanks, I think this is not working because I guess something in the preamble is overriding the line you sent, another alternative is that the bibliography style I'm using "apsr" does not allow the commnand you sent. The space in the bibliography goes to single sapce when I write \begin{singlespace}

BibTex Generated Bibliography

\end{singlespace} I guess something that goes like that (staring with 'begin') will work?    Thank you so much

Comment: I added the code to the question; please check it. However it's not correct: there is no `\topmatter` command in the `report` class. You show no usage of `setspace` other than around the bibliography, which means it is useless.

Comment: @egreg can you answer it for biblatex+biber?

Answer (score 8):

The `natbib` package provides a parameter just for doing what you need: add

```
\setlength{\bibsep}{\baselineskip} % or 6pt or ...
```

or whatever length you prefer; this will leave a blank line between two items.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is not working because I guess something in the preamble is overriding the line you sent, another alternative is that the bibliography style I'm using "apsr" does not allow the commnand you sent. The space in the bibliography goes to single sapce when I write \begin{singlespace} BibTex Generated Bibliography \end{singlespace} I guess something that goes like that (staring with 'begin') will work? Thank you so much –

Comment: @AlejandroOme Please, add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: This is what I'm running, does it help if I send the whole preamble?

\title{Three Essays on Meritocracy for Teachers and Teacher Quality in Colombia} 

\tableofcontents  

\listoffigures 

\listoftables

\topmatter{Acknowledgments}

\topmatter{Abstract}

\clearpage













\newpage

\newpage \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}  

\begin{singlespace}

Bibliography thing should go here

\end{singlespace}

Comment: @AlejandroOme Please, add it to your question, where it's better readable. A short version of the preamble is also needed (just the class and the relevant packages).

Answer (score 1):

I saw no one answered this question till now, since it is important question I want to share the solution I found [here](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~gautam/sj/blog/20140712-bibtex-spacing.html):

```
\usepackage{bibspacing}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{.2\baselineskip plus .05\baselineskip minus .05\baselineskip}
```

where the package `bibspacing` is available [here](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~gautam/sj/blog/20140712-bibtex-spacing/bibspacing.sty). It is just 8 lines long, so you could include it directly instead:

```
\newlength{\bibitemsep}\setlength{\bibitemsep}{.2\baselineskip plus .05\baselineskip minus .05\baselineskip}
\newlength{\bibparskip}\setlength{\bibparskip}{0pt}
\let\oldthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand\thebibliography[1]{%
  \oldthebibliography{#1}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{\bibitemsep}%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibparskip}%
}
```

At the [link](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~gautam/sj/blog/20140712-bibtex-spacing.html), some other solutions are linked.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Thanks for sharing your solution.